# Alias or Function for a Command

Tags: bash, alias, function

Sometimes (or may be all the time) an Alias and Function for a command works the same way. For example, following Alias and Function of Ping Command:

```
alias Pingoogle='ping -c 3 google.com && echo "internet working..."'
Pingoogle() {ping -c 3 google.com && echo "internet working...";}
```

works the same way by producing same output. But, My question is that in this situation which is more proper (or professional)? Setting Alias for such commands or Using Functions?

Comment: Good post. It means that using Alias is correct in my example.

Comment: I would suggest a function, not an alias, for your example. As soon as you start writing shell syntax (like `&&` or nested quotes) into your aliases it gets hard to reason about. Functions are much cleaner and you don't have to wrestle with escaping everything properly.